# Why doesn't Microsoft's NodeJS-Typescript starter project use types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I came across [Microsoft's NodeJS-Typescript Starter Project](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter) while searching around and found it strange that it doesn't actually use types. It basically looks exactly like any old Javascript NodeJS project.

For example, [at this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/src/server.ts#L44) instead of

```
const app = express();
```

wouldn't you expect it to be something like

```
const app: ExpressApp = express();
```

That's just one possible example. There are also no types given for functions, for parameters, etc.

Am I missing something or did Microsoft forget something?

**Link**: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you are missing something really important! :)

You don't actually have to tell the compiler that `app` is from type `Express`, it infers the type via `@types/express`. Since version 2 TypeScript got really smart and can infer a lot of types, so you don't have to explicitly tell the compiler what the result of `express()` is.

Of course you can do it, but I guess even Microsoft considers it not a good practice to add types all over the place. It just adds clutter to your code and lets TS look like (no offense) Java or C# ...which it isn't.

The only reason to implicitly declare a type is, when you're not assigning anything to your variable or the type would be `any` otherwise (because typings are missing for example).

Comment: Note that [in C# you can also use `var`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) instead of an explicit type in many cases. Personally I like to use `var` when it is pretty clear what type an expression will return, so my code stays brief and clean, but explicitly mention the type in other cases, for readability.

Comment: How does it know what type `Express` is ? I don't have `@types/express` downloaded so where did VSCode get it from and where can I see I actually see what types it knows about?

Comment: VSCode actually downloads typings for you in the background, even if you write JavaScript. If you're using `Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter` you've installed typings via `npm`. The express (and a lot of other) types are part of the `devDependencies`.